# What's the best way to name IDs and classes in CSS and HTML?

Tags: html, css, class, naming-conventions

When naming classes and IDs for CSS what is the best method to use. In this case I need there to be some kind of naming convention so that other people can pick up rules and understand how to name their own ids and classes using the same pattern. Any suggestions? Some of the sites we create can get pretty complex but use an overall structure header, content and footer. The naming must be efficient too.

I am not new to CSS. I am aware of giving them names that represent their structure etc., but  just want to know people opinions really and ways of doing this.

Comment: There really isn't a standard, as long as their descriptive and you use ids and classes correctly.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**The best advice is to use class with semantics in mind**

> **Good names don't change**
>
> Think about ***why*** you want something to
>   look a certain way, and not really
>   about ***how*** it should look. Looks can
>   always change but the reasons for
>   giving something a look stay the same.
>
> **Good names**
>       *warning*, *important*, *downloadableImage* and *submenu* are all
>   good names. They describe what a
>   certain element represents, and they
>   are not likely to change. A warning
>   will always remain a warning, no
>   matter how much the look of the page
>   changes.
>
> **Bad names**
>       *border4px*, *lighttext* and *prettybackground* are all examples of bad
>   names. You might fatten that border to
>   a whopping 5 pixels, or the background
>   may look pretty old after a while, and
>   not pretty at all. An advantage of
>   using CSS is that you won't have to
>   change much in order to change the
>   looks of your website. If you have to
>   change all light text into dark text,
>   and thus change all classes lighttext
>   to darktext in all your HTML pages,
>   you're likely to miss a few.

*from [this article](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/goodclassnames)*

Comment: Good call - was about to write the same sort of suggestions.

Comment: one thing I'd add is that it can be useful to have a handful of 'bad names', in particular to represent particular colour schemes. e.g. imagine you have a grid layout with every square given a random colour scheme with no real semantic meaning behind it. You can achieve this by giving each element a class such as "darkBlue", 'violet" etc

The majority of my classes follow the good names principle above, but it doesn't pay to try and enforce this totally rigidly all the time. But I doubt there's ever a good reason to break the rule when naming IDs.

Answer (score 5):

IDs can only be used once per page, so they are useful for major structural elements like "header" and "footer" (until HTML5 comes in and replaces those with native elements).

Classes can be used multiple times, and you can use multiple classes per element. They should be kept fairly generic - so instead of, say, `warningMessage` you could create one style `message` with the basic layout style, and then `warning`, `info`, and `error` styles with different colours. Then use `<div class="message warning">etc</div>`

You should also use HTML elements where applicable. Instead of `<span class="title">`, use a heading tag like `<h2>`.

As others have said, you can use underscores or hyphens or camel case - i.e. `my_style` or `my-style` or `myStyle`. Just choose a convention and stick to it (personally I use `my-style`). Jitendra suggested in a comment that lowercase is better when you're using gzip compression, which is true all round - for font names, hex colours, and it's worth naming files (e.g. background images) in lowercase anyway.

Sometimes coming up with good names can be hard. Think about *other places* you might use the same formatting. For example, if you want to put the author and date of an article below the title in smaller grey text, you might use `.authorAndDate`, but a better way would be `.byline`. This is still quite descriptive, and can be used in other places too, say, image captions.

Comment: a great answer ... that's what mine should have said! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

- ## header
- ## footer
- ## container
- .post
- .title

Those are the ones which come up in most of my projects but obviously it depends what you're doing. Just try to keep it logical.

Answer (score 1):

be descriptive and name your ids and classes in a semantic way, give them meaning

Answer (score 0):

There is no real naming convention. Just agree on one with your team and keep it consistent. For instance don't mix [camel case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) and snake case.

Try to be as description as possible when naming a class. Example:

```
.menu: bad
.head_menu: better

.wrapper: very bad
.main_content_wrapper: better
```

edit; Worse naming convention I saw is using the actual content of the styling. For instance:

```
.redButton
```

... because when I got to the code (legacy code), but "red button" was not red but blue (or something like that).

Try to use something that will not likely change, like the purpose of the class.

Comment: not that I know of. It's not very common for a programming language to use hyphens in a programing language

Comment: even though browsers seem to accept underscores in the names i think they weren't allowed in earlier css specs and are discouraged. hyphens ftw. http://devedge-temp.mozilla.org/viewsource/2001/css-underscores/

Comment: @tosh - that link suggests that they are only broken in Netscape Navigator 4.0. In which case you can't use divs either.

Answer (score 0):

The rules for naming an id or class attribute are simple. Keep it short, keep it consistent (i.e. if you use hyphens, underscores, or CamelCase for one, use the same format for the others), and make sure the name is based on the function or meaning of the element, NOT the style to be applied.

e.g.

`<span class="warningMessage">`, `<span class="warning-message">`, `<span class="warning-message">` are all perfectly acceptable.

`<span class="red-text">` would not be ... what happens when you change the colour to blue?

Comment: but lowercase is better always see here http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/lowercase/

Comment: I always tend to stick to lowercase and with hyphens for ease of editing

Answer (score 0):

I name my ids and classes for their purpose.  I try not to use descriptions that use color or direction.

For example, if I have a sidebar that is on the left, but it's for the main menu, I may name it `#main` or `#mainMenu`. The right sidebar in the same site would be `#altSidebar` or `#subMenu`.

I have many more classes than id's so naming them is a little harder.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I like to name IDs and Classes with lower-case names ranging from 1 to 3. Example would be ...

```
.user
.user-profile
.user-profile-picture
```

And if I want to style another user using classes ...

```
.user-2
.user-2-profile
.user-2-profile-picture
```

Like the others have said, you should not use attributes as names, rather, you should use elements like ...

```
user, picture, header, message, text, input, output.
```

And so on.

Do not use attributes, like ...

```
red, big, left, dark, light ...
```

These are bad because they could change from red to blue for example. But user will always be user.

Comment: what abt headings in section nested inside parent section (i.e. with Header1A, Header2A).