# Validate form with javascript having dash in form id

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

i have a form which i want to be validated with javascript before submitting. What i am trying is adding a filed to upload file with an id having a dash in its value eg id="file-upload". This doesn't work however if i remove the dash from the id ... the alert works fine..

here is the javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">function check(form) { if(form.file-upload.value===""){alert("Please select a file to upload !");form.file-upload.focus();return (false);} } </script>
```

and here is the form

```
<form method="post" action="" onSubmit="return check(this)" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <label>Upload Image:<span class="asterixRequired">*</span></label>
    <fieldset><input type="file" id="file-upload" name="file-upload"></fieldset> 
                                   </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Javascript and CSS, using dashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119629/javascript-and-css-using-dashes) as well as this question/solution:
http://www.aspmessageboard.com/showthread.php?t=125142

Obviously JavaScript has problems with the dash, so you may have to use
 `document.forms['formname'].elements['field-with-dashes'].value`
(from the above link) to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

The standard method to find elements by ID is `.getElementById()`:

```
document.getElementById("file-upload").focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try validate jQuery plugin?
take a look at here :

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/