# Sencha Touch: Declaring class using Ext.define()

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.3

I am new to Sencha Touch(a js framework for cross platform apps).
While, learning sencha , I came across a strange problem, I searched out almost every where but couldn't find any.

**Problem**
I declared a Model named "UserPass" using

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.UserPass',{other params});
```

I connected that model to a store , added some values everything was working fine.
Then for some reason , I changed the name of the model from "UserPass" to "User-Pass" i.e like.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.User-Pass',{other params});
```

It stopped working.

I tried to change the Model names more times using 'dash' and without dash.
With 'UserPass', the code works fine but using 'User-Pass' the code stops working.

Is this a problem with the "dash" between "User" and "Pass" in the name of model?
Or anything else that is not coming to my wit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not allowed in sencha simply.
May be as using hyphens is deprecated/not allowed in variables in javascript.

See this link please .
Parrots answer explains good.
[Javascript and CSS, using dashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119629/javascript-and-css-using-dashes)