# css tips for naming classes of html elements

Tags: html, css

I am trying to find a tutorial online or some advice in order to construct and name my class names in the css file or files, in a way to avoid frustration, enhance readability and re usability.
Any tips or tutorials around?

Comment: Check this may be that's you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222731/should-css-class-names-like-floatleft-that-directly-describe-the-attached-styl

Comment: Also worth the look: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Name your classes based on what kind of content they are rather than the styles being applied or their location.  For example `div.navigation` is better than `div.leftSidebar`, which is better than `div.grayBox`.

For more information and examples, read [this](http://sixrevisions.com/css/css-tips/css-tip-2-structural-naming-convention-in-css/).

Comment: Thank you very much for you advice, I will accept your answer as correct since the link you provided game me the answers i needed.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't have to be difficult. Common sense will do. My rule of thumb is, if you want to give something a certain style, just think of the reason you want to do that and use that reason as a class name.  If you want to make something bold because it's important, use `class="important"`. Simple as that.